# Push large artifacts though API gitlab

Tags: gitlab, artifacts

When we try to push large artifacts though API gitlab, we getting error:

> WARNING: Uploading artifacts as "archive" to coordinator... POST https://gitlab.company.local/api/v4/jobs/45623/artifacts: 500 Internal Server Error  id=45623 responseStatus=500 Internal Server Error status=500 token=*****
> WARNING: Retrying...

gitlab version: v16.7.2
OS: Ubuntu 18.04
gitlab runner version: v16.7.0
OS: Ubuntu 20.04

Gitlab running as service on hist

Please help to solve this problem.

We changed:

- updated gitlab from v16.4.1 to v16.7.2
- updated runners
- `gitlab_rails['artifacts_enabled'] = true`
- `gitlab_rails['artifacts_path'] = "/var/opt/gitlab/gitlab-rails/shared/artifacts"`
- `nginx['enable'] = true`
- `nginx['client_max_body_size'] = '2500m'`
- updated rights for /var/opt/gitlab/gitlab-rails/shared folder
- changed settings for upload artifacts on global and local side